The resource limit isn't being enforced on the Kubernetes cluster
I'm studying Kubernetes with a Kind cluster on my local machine. When I installed several apps using Helm charts, they consumed a lot of resources and shut down easily.
So, I set resource requests/limits for one of them and monitored it with Prometheus. However, I noticed that it still used more memory than the limit.
Why is the pod still alive? I thought the pod would be killed because it used more memory than its limit.

Here is my values.yaml (Strimzi Kafka cluster operator).
...

defaultImageRegistry: quay.io
defaultImageRepository: strimzi
defaultImageTag: 0.43.0

image:
  registry: ""
  repository: ""
  name: operator
  tag: ""
  # imagePullSecrets:
  #   - name: secretname
logVolume: co-config-volume
logConfigMap: strimzi-cluster-operator
logConfiguration: ""
logLevel: ${env:STRIMZI_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}
fullReconciliationIntervalMs: 120000

...


resources:
  limits:
    memory: 384Mi
    cpu: 1000m
  requests:
    memory: 384Mi
    cpu: 200m

Thanks in advance for your response. :)
Edited:
And... how do you find the appropriate requests/limits for each app? Is it just through trial and error?

Why do you believe the Pod is using more than 384 MiB?  What language is your application implemented in; is it something where memory is proactively released (C, C++, Rust) or garbage-collected (Java, Go, most interpreted languages)?  In garbage-collected languages especially, it's possible for the garbage collector to hold on to memory it's not using, and so Pod-level resource statistics might show a high memory usage when the application will run fine if given less memory.

I think that limits are enforced by cgroup. Now as it's not you could raise an issue for kind

Please refer to the document Create a LimitRange that you can create a Limit Range in namespace.
It is currently not possible to enforce LimitRange and ResourceQuota cluster-wide, that is, providing defaults for every namespace. I'm aware of at least one discussion to potentially change this.
